# Django NoReverseMatch when trying to logout

Tags: django

I have a django view function `signout` that  I want to call form a form/template. When i click logout, it calls the function but the redirect after doesnt work. I get the message `Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: POST '/account/signout'>' not found. '<WSGIRequest: POST '/account/signout'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

```
Urls.py

    urlpatterns = [
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
    path('signout', views.signout, name='signout'),
    path('dashboard', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

```
   Views.py

    def signout(request):

        if(request.method == 'POST'):
            auth.logout(request)
            messages.success(request, 'You are logged out!')
            return redirect(request, 'index')
```

```
   Template form
     <form action="{% url 'signout'%}" id="logout" method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="hidden">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
              Log Out</button>
     </form>
```

What is going wrong?? The rest of routes work just fine and they are declared the same as signout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong in your view .You don't need parenthesis while checking the if condition and redirect doesn't take the request parameter.

Change your view like this

```
     def signout(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            auth.logout(request)
            messages.success(request, 'You are logged out!')
            return redirect('index')
```